# Help for properly writing simple derivative expression

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax, expression-manipulation

I need help to write the following expression (only 1 iteration):

f(x) = ...some basic function...

f[X0,...,Xp] = f<sup>(p)</sup>(x<sub>0</sub>) / p!

What I have so far:

```
f[x_] := ...some basic function...
MyFunc[f_, arr_, i_, 
p_] := (D[ f[arr[[0]] ], {arr[[0]], p} ]) / p!;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
MyFunc[y__] := (D[f[x], {x, Length[{y}]}]/(Length[{y}])!) /. 
  x -> First[{y}]
```

Example:

```
    f[x_] := Sin[x]

    MyFunc[3, 5]

    (*-(Sin[3]/2)*)
```

Comment: Could you explain (or give url) what is "/." and "->"?

Comment: This is ReplaceAll function. http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html

Comment: ah, now I get it, thanks :)

Comment: Even after a few years of using Mathematica, I sometimes am confused by strings of `@`, etc.  Such syntax is listed [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Syntax.html).